# Does sickened condition apply to demons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, conditions

Can a Demon get into the sickened condition, e.g. by the sickening offensive investigator talent?

Comment: Hi tmartin, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Your question might benefit from adding clarification about what has you uncertain this would or wouldn't occur (I don't know for sure, not being an avid Pathfinder player myself). It would suggest research effort, but it would also mean we could clarify whatever's going on behind your uncertainty as well.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm going to go out on a limb and suppose that asker was either told by the GM or himself ruled that demons and similar powerful beings from the lower reaches were immune to the condition sikenened because they couldn't actually get sick. Or something. ("I am a mighty [pib fienb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/pit-fiend/)!" "A what?" "A  pib fienb!" "A what?" "A pib fienb! Shub up, mortal. I hab a colb!") But, yeah, I'd like some context, too.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan : Yes, it is precisely this argumentation that has been made. As is so often the case with rpg, it is a matter of somehow combining flavor text, rules and common sense. Referring to your answer, I was able to persuade the gm to accept the sickened condition.

Comment: Cool enough. And just in case more ammo's needed, despite them being immune to poison, demons are *not* immune to disease.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A creature is not immune to a condition unless an effect makes the creature immune to the condition or the condition says that such a creature is immune to the condition. This includes the condition [sickened](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Sickened). The general descriptions of the condition sickened and of both [outsiders](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/) and [demons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/) grants demons no *general* immunity to the condition sickened. *Specific* demons may exceptions. (I mean, really, there are *a lot* of different kinds of demons!)

This means that, for example, the investigator talent [sickening offensive](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/investigator-talents/paizo-investigator-talents/sickening-offensive/), an extraordinary ability, can give the typical demon the condition sickened.

***Note:*** While it may seem odd, a condition is often not literally representative of its name. For example, an investigator that uses her sickening offensive talent to cause a demon to gain the condition sickened is probably not *giving the demon a brief, nasty cold but, instead, striking the demon in a region that's* so *important to the demon (use your imagination… or, y'know, don't) that the demon suffers in the same way it would were it actually ill.*